# Toggling chrome extension by clicking browser action

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've read similar posts ([This one seems to be what every similar topic links to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528009/how-to-toggle-actions-of-a-browser-action)) and I'm not entirely sure how to implement the functionality where a second click on a browser action will close the popup rather than just re-load it. I attempted to implement similar to what the linked stackoverflow post introduced without success.

From my understanding, we need to be using browseraction.onClicked listeners. Can this be achieved by using conditionals and window.close(), perhaps?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I thought I have a nice way of doing it, but unfortunately there's a race condition.. And working around it hurts reliability. It really needs [this API](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=436489) to work, alas it's not in Stable yet.

Comment: @Zig Mandel, I tried to implement the code in the linked Stack Overflow post in the approved response. It generated no change in functionality.

Comment: Something you need to know is that `chrome.browserAction.onClicked` is not triggered at all if you have a popup set. I tried a solution that unsets the popup for as long as the popup is open; problem is, the popup closes _before_ the click processing considers whether it needs to open a popup, and delaying it by a set time (even if it's 10ms) is bad form.. I can still post my "dirty" solution, if you wish.

Comment: What? Second browser action click closes the popup seems to be native behavior for me, on stable 42.

Comment: Daniel, this may be an issue with when I set default_popup, but it is an issue based on my web research that is not unique to me. Can you possibly share your manifest code?

Comment: @DanielHerr It may be OS-dependent, even.. On Win8, it closes and immediately reopens it.

Comment: I am on Chrome OS. And it seems to work as you describe when I put enough pressure on the trackpad so that it clicks, but if I just tap it will close and not reopen.

Comment: It seems this may be a bug only affecting some operating systems according to a couple threads I found on google code forums.